# set button Visible in another acticty with Preferences setting

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I've a problem to set button Visibility through another Activity

Code explanation:

First,  `menu.xml`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/f1"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button1"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/f2lock"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/levellocked"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/f2"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button2"
    android:visibility="gone" />
```

`f2` button used for intent `leveltwo.class` but it still set to GONE,
`f2lock` is ImageView for levellocked

Second, menu.java

```
public class menu extends Activity {

Button f1, f2;
ImageView f2lock;    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.famouslevel);
    f1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.f1);      

    f1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent level1 = new Intent ();
            level1.setClassName ("com.example.game", "com.example.game.levelone");
            startActivityForResult (level1, 0);              
        }             
    });     
}   

public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent level1){
    super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, level1); 
    f2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f2);      
    f2lock=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.f2lock);

    switch (resultCode) {
        case 2:  f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
    }      

    f2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent level2 = new Intent ();
            level2.setClassName ("com.example.game", "com.example.game.leveltwo");
            startActivityForResult (level2, 0);              
        }             
    });       
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.splashscreen, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

following code to call `levelone.java` with a Result

so in `levelone.java` i put the code like this

```
 public void onClick(View v){
                  setResult (2);
                  finish();          
                  }
                });
```

the code function is to send Result (2) to `menu.class` when `level.class` is finish();

```
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent level1){
    super.onActivityResult (requestCode, resultCode, level1); 
    f2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.f2);      
    f2lock=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.f2lock);

    switch (resultCode) {
        case 2:  f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);            
    }
```

the code above is to receive result (2) from `levelone.class` and do `case 2` function

the question is how to use and set SharedPreferences in case 2? so the f2 and f2lock visibility will saved

because i have try the SharedPreferences code but nothing is happen, f2 button still GONE and f2lock imageview still VISIBLE

i mean is like this:

Like a game, when user have done level 1 so level 2 will unlocked

but in here i make button is VISIBLE when level 1 is done

Comment: Hey there. I can help you solve this issue, but am a little confused what exactly you're asking. It's probably me being a silly goose, but still -- mind explaining in a comment, or doing a tl;dr of your question, so that I can give you an adequate response, please.

Comment: With a lot more abstraction and less reference to your code, I should add.

Comment: the code i mean is like a normal game bro, when level 1 completed level 2 is unlocked

Comment: Yep, I think I got it! Writing up an answer now.

Comment: @Sipty bro can you help me in here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32025103/make-button-visible-with-staticclass-and-save-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I've understood your question correctly. Please, correct me if I have not!

The way I see things is that there are several different solution to your use case:

The first one, would be a proper `SharedPreferences` implementation, directly building on top of your existing code. In my eyes, that is not the best approach, as it is misusing the point of SharedPreferences.

Another way of doing this would be to implement callbacks into the different activities, but that would just get tedious, as you add more levels.

My solution to this would be to have a different class with static values, which would store the progress of the player. This can also be evolved to a file, which you write to the disk, if you want the progress to remain between sessions.

You would just need to check the player's progress, whenever you need, with a simple interface function like `getPlayerProgress()`, which would return, for example, an integer, explaining which is the maximum level achieved. This also assumes that you handle the interface with a seperate function, which would be called at the beginning of every level/game start ect. A name for that function would be `updateLevel()`, for example. Does this make sense to you?

Here is a sample implementation, of the two classes I mentioned:

```
/**
 * A static class, which handles all player progress, throughout the lifespan of the app.
 *
 */
static class PlayerProgress {
    // We set progress to static, so it would be alive, no matter what activity you're in.
    private static int progress = 1;

    /**
     * Update the player's progress.
     * @param levelNumber: latest level number.
     */
    public static void updateProgress(int levelNumber) {
        progress = levelNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Get the player's progress.
     * @return the latest level number.
     */
    public static int getPlayerProgress() {
        return progress;
    }
}

/**
 * The gui handler would need to be called, every time you need to update the screen to the
 * appropriate level and it's assets. (Buttons, activities ect.)
 * 
 * I would implement a MainActivity, which would handle the different screens. 
 *
 */
class guiHandler {
    public void updateLevel() {
        int progress = PlayerProgress.getPlayerProgress();
        /*
         * Add your 
         */
        switch(progress) {
        case 1:
            /*
             * Add the code, which would display level one. 
             * This would include all button visibilities and maybe load level resources ect.
             */
            break;
        case 2:
            /*
             * Same as above.
             */
            break;

        // You can expand this to as many levels you'd like. 
        }
    }
}
```

Again, if I have misunderstood, please correct me. If you'd like sample code, by all means, just ask.

I hope you have a lovely day.

Comment: hmm so this getPlayerProgress() is like load the last data saved in the game?

Comment: It would access the information, which you were trying to save with shared preferences, in this case: the players progress. I forgot to mention, that I am assuming the use of an interface handler function. Allow me to edit it in for you.

Comment: Sure can, let me whip up something for you.

Comment: I updated the answer. Was it clear enough, to portray my suggestion to you?

Comment: eh i have a question sipty. first, did i need to use startActivityForResult (levels, 0); and onActivityresult or not?

Comment: second, without sharedpreferences the progress will saved?

Comment: You don't need to start activity for result and it's pairing. This is a solution without shared preferences. It is just a help class, to be used in your main game loop. : ) You will need to use xml, show/hide your buttons.

Comment: Oh ok i will learn this code and put in my project. Thanks for help me Sipty

Answer (score 1):

Write below code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("key", 2);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

and check in on Activity result :

```
public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent level1) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, level1);
    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(level1.getExtras() != null){
            int key = level1.getIntExtra("key",0);
            if(key == 2){
                f2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            f2lock.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but how i put preferences in there? so the button visibility is saved?